# How to have a conditional async action in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using vue.js 2.* . I want to perform an action on an item but first, I check if this item exists and if not, I go fetch it through an API. My current code looks like this :

```
if (myItem == null) {
    this.goFetchItem().then(response => {
    myItem.performAction()
  })
} else {
  myItem.performAction()
}
```

I'd like to know if it possible to have somthing in the idea of :

```
if (myItem == null) {
    this.goFetchItem()
}
//And then, when item is fetched :
myItem.performAction()
```

For now,,in the second example, it seems `goFetchItem()` is executed asynchronoulsy, so `myItem` is still `null` when trying to perform the action.

Comment: `in the second example, it seems goFetchItem() is executed asynchronoulsy, so myItem is still null` -- That's why your first example uses `.then`.

Comment: I know, the first example is my actual code. I am curious to know if there is a solution to write something looking like the second example, since I only write the line `performAction()` once. Shorter and cleaner. But I can't stick a `then` after the `if`. My code works, i'm juste trying to make it cleaner.

Comment: Probably you would prefer to wrap the logic `check myItem is null then fetch from backend` into one promise, then always call `perfromAction` inside `Promise.final`

Comment: the duplicate lists all the possible ways to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `async / await`?

```
async function foo() {
    if (myItem == null) {
        await this.goFetchItem()
    }

    myItem.performAction()
}
```

check this out.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

[Javascript Promises vs Async Await. Difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34401389/javascript-promises-vs-async-await-difference)

Comment: Perfect ! I did not know about the `await` keyword (pretty new to JS). Thank you !