# React Native - Can't perform a state change on unmounted component error even with isMounted flag

Tags: react-native, graphql, react-state

I am working on a React Native project and I have a function that makes a GraphQL query:

```
 getPosts = async () => {
    const result = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listPosts))
    if(this.state.isMounted){
      this.setState({ posts: result.data.Posts.items,
        isLoading: false, isMounted: false})
    }
  }
```

This function is called in the `componentDidMount` function. I also have a `isMounted` field in the `state` that is initialized to `false`. At the very top of the `componentDidMount` function I have:

```
this.setState({ isMounted: true })
```

Regardless, I am still getting a warning about trying to set the state on an component that is unmounted. I should also mention that this Component is called from `this.props.navigation.navigate`call.

Comment: use a plain property `this._isMounted` instead of `this.state.isMounted`

Comment: I get a warning that `this.isMounted` is deprecated and that I should just clean up subscriptions and pending requests in `componentWillUnmount`. I believe I'm doing that though.

Comment: 1) I'm talking about your own property called this._isMounted (or some another name you want) and not deprecated React property this.isMounted. The _isMounted property should NOT be a state property. 2) No. You're not doing that how they asking, you're just trying to make your own version of the deprecated isMounted API. You don't cancel any subscription there at all, you just try to ignore the results of those.

Comment: I have `.unsubscribe()` in my `componentWillUnmount` for my subscriptions. Isn't that how you're supposed to clean them up? I made a `_isMounted` prop NOT in the state, but that doesn't seem to fix the warning.

Comment: Yes, you should cancel all subscriptions, stop requests, clear timers, etc. And not try to change state after unmounting, but you are probably missing something. Since we don't have any code to see how you do this, it's hard to guess what exactly is wrong.

Comment: I want to clarify. Which API does mentioned `.unsubscribe ()` belong to? :) Don't take it literally - for example, for API.graphql () you have to use its cancellation API call - API.cancel (promise) to stop the request when your component unmounting. Each pending asynchronous function / promise resource must be stopped / disposed by using the cancellation API provided in each case.

Comment: Ah ok yes, the `.unsubscribe` is from the API api. So for example, in my `getPosts` method up above, would I call `this.getPosts.cancel()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Why you need the `isMounted` state? If you are using this state just to be a condition to set the state `posts`, you could just call the `getPosts` method inside the `componentDidMount` function and should work as you expected:

```
async componentDidMount(){
  await getPosts()
}
```

You got it?
Waiting for your feedback about my answer. Thx :)

Comment: I am calling the getPosts inside the componentDidMount. Maybe it’s an issue with something else then...

Comment: But I want you to remove this ``ìsMounted```state, you got it? So your ```getPosts``` would be like this: ```getPosts = async () => {
      const result = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listPosts))
      this.setState({ posts: result.data.Posts.items,
        isLoading: false})
}``` Try like this and should work.

Comment: yes that’s how it was originally, but I had the same result. I just added the isMounted stuff because is saw it in another Stack Overflow post

Comment: Oh now I know what should be the problem, write the componentDidMount like this: ```async componentDidMount(){
    await this.getPosts()
}```

Comment: So that does seem to make the problem go away. Why is it that using the `await` in front of the call works, but not if I change the code to do this:

Comment: `getPosts = async () => {
    await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listSoundwaves))
    .then( result => {
      this.setState({ posts: result.data.listSoundwaves.items,
        isLoading: false, isMounted: false})
    })
  }`

Comment: Isn't that essentially the same

Comment: @ecain using `await` and `then` is mixing different conventions ... you don't need `isMounted` at all ... error usually means data arrived [too late] but component was removed

Comment: but since there is an `await` on the actual graphQL call, how could it arrive "too late" ?

Comment: proper question would be why component disappears before its state can be updated

Comment: @xadm ah ok who controls when a component goes out of scope?

Comment: @ecain IDK, it's your project/you know the structure/conditions/whatever

Comment: I think that your code is not working because you're mixing the ``àwait``` keyword with the ```.then``` that is a ```promise```syntax, you got it?  The use of ``àsync/await``` is a optimization of ``` promises. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54495711/async-await-vs-then-which-is-the-best-for-performance -> This post is interesting to read about this subject. Waiting for your feedback, Thx :). @ecain