# Is the return type using .then different from without it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch-api

My code works with the following:

```
export async function FetchAPI(props){
    const url = `www.website.com/${props}`
    let res = await fetch(url)
    let response = await res.json()
    return response
}
```

But when I try to clean up the code using better practices, I get error for the below code saying it is returning undefined.

```
export async function FetchAPI(props){
    const url = `www.website.com/${props}`
    fetch(url)
        .then((resp => {
          resp.json()
          return resp
     }))
}
```

Anyone understand the differences and how I can get the second one to work?

Comment: You're missing `return fetch(url)...` in order to return the promise. Also, your first code snippet is much cleaner IMO. Also also, you're not using `resp.json()` properly. You should have `return fetch(url).then(resp => resp.json())` or `return fetch(url).then(resp => { return resp.json() })`

Comment: also, `await` is better than `then` in terms of speed.. can you explain how `then` is a *"better practise"*?

Comment: Also see this: [What is the difference between JavaScript promises and async await?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34401389/2873538)

Comment: @TheBombSquad have you got a reference for that _speed_ statement. AFAIK, `await` is just syntactic sugar for the exact same process (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54497100/283366)

Comment: I wonder why using thenable rather than async/await is better practice.

Comment: My first code snippet returned a 'Missing HSTS Header' warning. "The web-application does not define an HSTS header, leaving it vulnerable to attack." Not sure if it's because of code elsewhere though.

Comment: The return type is the same, once you fix the mistake about not returning the fetch.  The both return a Promise that resolves to the response.

Comment: @Phil no await is not just "syntactic sugar", the engine will actually better handle promise reactions and in some cases will avoid useless wrapping Promises generally do. e.g  `.then(<Promise>)` will wrap that <Promise> in a new Promise internally meaning two microtask will get scheduled, while `await <Promise>` will queue a single microtask. So yes, async/await can be more performant than non async ones (and that's just on the theoretical aspect, in practice, most engines even do have further optimizations only for async functions.) See https://v8.dev/blog/fast-async

Comment: @Phil Actually I noticed later-on that jfriend00 did already link to that post in their answer you did link to :) And their point that performances should not be decisive in which one to use is still true, the difference in terms of performances should not matter, and if it does, it's probably because something else went wrong in the code's design.

Comment: @Phil `await` isnt JUST "syntactic sugar".. it will make things WAIT on it to finish whereas `then` wont.. if I had a promise that resolves in 3000ms(`long`) and another promise that resolves in 2000ms(`short`).. if I `await(long);await(short)`, long resolves first, **HOWEVER** if I `long.then();short.then()`, short resolves first

Comment: @TheBombSquad that's totally different code. The equivalent syntax would be `long.then(() => short)`

Answer (score 2):

The correct code for the `.then()` version is this:

```
export function FetchAPI(props){
    const url = `http://www.website.com/${props}`;
    return fetch(url).then(resp => {
        return resp.json();
    });
}
```

> Is the return type using .then different from without it?

This fixed version would generate the same exact returned results as your `await` version with the same URL.  Both would return a promise that would resolve/reject based on the results of the fetch and the JSON conversion of the body.

Note: URLs used in Javascript programming should contain the protocol as shown here.

> I wonder why using thenable rather than async/await is better practice.

Async/await is a more modern syntax.  When sequencing multiple asynchronous operations or branching based on asynchronous results, it is pretty much always simpler to write, read and debug with `async/await` than using `.then()`.

When you just have a single asynchronous operation, you can sometimes just return that promise and using `async/await` doesn't necessarily provide any advantages.  It's entirely up to the designer of the code which one to use - either can work just fine when written properly.

There are times when a simple `.catch()` is cleaner than putting a try/catch around the whole block too for localized error handling.  Like many things with coding style, there's no absolute right and wrong, just opinions on what looks like the cleanest code.

Also, if you want your code to run in older Javascript environments that don't support `async/await`, then you may need to use `.then()` and `.catch()` or transpile your code to an older target.

For a related discussion see [Async / await vs then which is the best for performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54495711/async-await-vs-then-which-is-the-best-for-performance/54497100#54497100).

Comment: yeaaa... mb tyy