# Async/await vs then in React example, only async/await working, why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch-api

I am trying to follow the two examples at https://blog.logrocket.com/modern-api-data-fetching-methods-react/ described in sections "Using the JavaScript Fetch API" and "Using the async/await syntax".

I am attempting to apply both methods to https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random inside a React app. I managed to get the second approach to work, but not the first. I am trying to understand better the difference between the two methods, particularly whether there is a fundamental issue with the first approach or whether I am simply not implementing it correctly.

I only have a vague understanding of asynchronicity and promises. I read through
[Async / await vs then which is the best for performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54495711/async-await-vs-then-which-is-the-best-for-performance) but I don't feel like I have a good grasp on the issue yet. Perhaps someone could use the example below as an opportunity to help me understand the underlying concepts better?

**"Then" Implementation**

```
import {useEffect} from 'react';

export default function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random/`)
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((jsonResponse) => {
      console.log(jsonResponse)
    });
   }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
    </div>
  );
}
```

Result in "Failed to fetch" error, see https://codesandbox.io/s/great-albattani-eu5zq1?file=/src/App.js

**"Async/await" implementation"**

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const getDogPic = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random");
    const dog = await response.json();
    console.log(dog);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getDogPic();
  }, []);

  return <div className="App"></div>;
}
```

Runs successfully, see https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-chaplygin-zr1pft?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the trailing slash from your first example

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random`)
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((jsonResponse) => {
      console.log(jsonResponse)
    });
   }, []);
```

There's nothing special to understand here, that API endpoint just doesn't work with a trailing slash for whatever reason.