# window.crypto.subtle.importkey and sign issue

Tags: typescript, cryptography, subtlecrypto

In typescript I have the following code to sign a message with the ecdsa method and the SHA-512 algorithm.

```
const pem = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQgUIcMiv/YpEgR1CKRsL6sS85BVo6lYft/S5nIjTlCHvihRANCAATykP7bc8\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"
    // fetch the part of the PEM string between header and footer
    const pemHeader = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----";
    const pemFooter = "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
    const pemContents = pem.substring(pemHeader.length, pem.length - pemFooter.length);
    // base64 decode the string to get the binary data
    const binaryDerString = window.atob(pemContents);
    // convert from a binary string to an ArrayBuffer
    const binaryDer = this.str2ab(binaryDerString);

    return window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
      "pkcs8",
      binaryDer,
      {
        name: "RSA-PSS",
        hash: "SHA-512",
      },
      true,
      ["sign"]
    );
  }
```

I have this method to sign the message:

```
createSignature2(){

    let privateKey = this.importPrivateKey();
    console.log(privateKey)
    let data = this.str2ab("Test buffer")
  
    let sign = window.crypto.subtle.sign(
      {
          name: "ECDSA",
          hash: {name: "SHA-512"}, //can be "SHA-1", "SHA-256", "SHA-384", or "SHA-512"
      },
      privateKey, //from generateKey or importKey above
      data //ArrayBuffer of data you want to sign
  )
  .then(function(signature){
      //returns an ArrayBuffer containing the signature
      console.log(new Uint8Array(signature));
  })
  .catch(function(err){
      console.error(err);
  });
  }
```

I get an error:

```
Argument of type 'Promise<CryptoKey>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CryptoKey'.
  Type 'Promise<CryptoKey>' is missing the following properties from type 'CryptoKey': algorithm, extractable, type, usages
```

What am I missing here?

Thank you,

Comment: Note that besides the correct answer from Topaco, something has gone wrong copy  / pasting the key. That base 64 does not represent a PKCS#8 encoded private key at all, even the ASN.1 DER decoding fails.

Comment: I know, but I didn't want to expose my complete private key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key import is incorrect. `RSA-PSS` imports an RSA key (for a signing/verification with RSASSA-PSS as padding). However, for ECDSA it makes no sense to import an RSA key. RSA and ECDSA are completely different algorithms. Instead of the RSA key, an EC key must be imported and thereby the EC curve must be specified.
Regarding the posted key itself: As already mentioned in the comment, this does not correspond to any valid format and it represents neither an RSA nor an EC key.
Another point is about the syntax used. The code often applies `then()`, but also constructions where the `await` keyword is missing. Here, either only `async/await` (in a correct way) or only `then()` should be used consistently (s. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54495711/9014097) for the difference).
Furthermore, `str2ab()` is missing.

The following code shows an example of importing an EC key including signing with ECDSA. P-521 is used as curve. As private key a PEM encoded sample EC key in PKCS#8 format is applied.
In the code the `async/await` syntax is applied (because this is clearer in my opinion). [`str2ab()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/importKey#pkcs_8_import) is taken from the WebCrypto API documentation. `ab2str()` is the inverse function to this. The signature is Base64 encoded for display:

```js
(async () => {

createSignature2(); // Fix: apply consistently async/await syntax

async function createSignature2(){

    const privateKey = await importPrivateKey();
    console.log(privateKey)

    const data = str2ab("Test buffer")
    const sign = await window.crypto.subtle.sign({name: "ECDSA",hash: {name: "SHA-512"}}, privateKey, data);
    console.log(window.btoa(ab2str(sign)));
}

async function importPrivateKey() {   
    const pem = `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
                 MIHuAgEAMBAGByqGSM49AgEGBSuBBAAjBIHWMIHTAgEBBEIA3G3l+QFixI4fD4zW
                 lC9n7xnT/7MS4bm6Ge6KXPmesmy9AARSdysdhWLXq51hvd/4F4Rd+ZYWn8bdeN58
                 zOJdRAOhgYkDgYYABAGBW8V/nf4yXdePGpotIL8WNR1182yBdcztCpWQUkL9TOEy
                 vhhnf8SwtRDglbjCBiVONw4+WjC3pRfo3yTmee+mEQE3peJArA1zOFz9WJZhigA9
                 aK3t8BUbisZ38C4jcRuGgaBYUvg3ndMdqZnsNdbcg7sKOM9szCUvzGWkIWn2l4lW
                 zA==
                 -----END PRIVATE KEY-----`;
    const pemHeader = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----";
    const pemFooter = "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
    const pemContents = pem.substring(pemHeader.length, pem.length - pemFooter.length);
    const binaryDerString = window.atob(pemContents);
    const binaryDer = str2ab(binaryDerString);
    return await window.crypto.subtle.importKey("pkcs8", binaryDer,{name: "ECDSA",namedCurve: "P-521"}, true, ["sign"]); // Fix: import ECDSA key
}

function str2ab(str) {
    const buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
    const bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
    for (let i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
        bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return buf;
}
  
function ab2str(buf) {
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buf));
}

})();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Solved my issue. And clear explanation.