# Is it better to use asynchandler always instead of just using async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Forgive me; I'm a beginner.
Using 'asyncHandler' makes it easier to handle errors than directly using 'async' functions in Nodejs.
So should I use it every time instead of directly using 'async' or when should I use it?

Comment: Please provide a code sample so we’re all on the same page what exactly you mean.

Comment: This link may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54495711/async-await-vs-then-which-is-the-best-for-performance