# Benefits from async await vs return promise

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I'm just trying to understand the benefits of this:

```
const populateUsers = done => {
  User.remove({}).then(async () => {
    const userOne = new User(users[0]).save();
    const userTwo = new User(users[1]).save();
    const usersProm = await Promise.all([userOne, userTwo]).then(() => done());
    return usersProm;
  });
};
```

over this:

```
const populateUsers = done => {
  User.remove({})
    .then(() => {
      const userOne = new User(users[0]).save();
      const userTwo = new User(users[1]).save();

      return Promise.all([userOne, userTwo]);
    })
    .then(() => done());
};
```

I came to this problem because eslint suggested my to use async in this function, and I remember the concept, make it work in my app, but I'm not sure why should I use this instead of the original way

Comment: one is sugar for the other.

Comment: Please link (or at least name) the eslint rule that recommended this

Comment: @HereticMonkey That's a C# question?

Comment: @Bergi D'oh! Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/34401389/215552 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your first version does not go *all the way*. Do this:

```
const populateUsers = done => {
  User.remove({}).then(async () => {
    const userOne = new User(users[0]).save();
    const userTwo = new User(users[1]).save();
    await Promise.all([userOne, userTwo]);
    const usersProm = await done();
    return usersProm;
  });
};
```

There is no difference, it is just that code without these `then` callbacks is somewhat easier to read.

You might even apply it to the outer function:

```
const populateUsers = async () => {
  await User.remove({});
  const userOne = new User(users[0]).save();
  const userTwo = new User(users[1]).save();
  await Promise.all([userOne, userTwo]);
  const usersProm = await done();
  return usersProm;
};
```

Now `populateUsers` returns the promise instead of `undefined`.

As concluded in comments: you get an error because `populateUsers`returns a promise and accepts a `done` callback argument, while one of these is expected, not both.

Comment: In order to be sure, when I use await, I do not need use then() because only until the await promise "ends" my code will not continue, then I just have to call the done().

I modified your code in order to understand.

Would this work too, or it will give me some problems in the future?

const populateUsers = done => {
  User.remove({}).then(async () => {
    const userOne = new User(users[0]).save();
    const userTwo = new User(users[1]).save();
    await Promise.all([userOne, userTwo]);
    return done();
  });
};

Comment: When `await` is encountered, the `async` function returns immediately with a promise. Execution continues there as usual. When the call stack is empty and the promise at the `await` resolves, then magically the function's context is restored, and continues there. Yes, your variant is fine too.

Comment: Ok, I got it with the call stack.
But, when I used the last function with the await User.remove({}), It didn't pass the test.
"     Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both." Why this is not working?

Comment: I guess you get that error in the way you call `populateUsers`. The context where you call it will expect a returned promise or the `done` argument, not both.

Comment: I deleted the done callback and now everything works as inteded, thanks

Comment: @trincot Note, no value is `return`ed from the function at the code at the first example at the answer. A value is returned from within `.then()`, though not from the `populateUsers` function, that is, `return User.remove({}).then()`

Comment: @guest271314, I assume this comment is for the OP, as this is the behaviour presented in the question.

Comment: @trincot The answer states "Do this:". Not sure if it is clear to OP why the function would  result in `undefined`, or an error if built-in `.then()` is chained. Even though the question is about returning a `Promise`, no value is returned from the first example code at the question. Though you did point out _"Now `populateUsers` returns the promise instead of `undefined`."_

Answer (score 0):

Your original code was totally fine.

No, there is no benefit in using the code from your first snippet. You should [avoid mixing `await` and `.then(…)` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54387912/1048572)! To use `async`/`await`, you'd make the whole function `async`, not the `then` callback:

```
async function populateUsers(done) {
  await User.remove({})
  const userOne = new User(users[0]).save();
  const userTwo = new User(users[1]).save();

  await Promise.all([userOne, userTwo]);
  return done();
}
```

(Probably you would also remove that `done` callback - the function already returns a promise)

Comment: Ok, with your answer and the one from Trincot, I understood exactly what does the async functions with the await, and why I got an error like this "Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both."

I removed the done callback and everything worked as inteded. thanks