# How to use promise in JS and Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have connected my sql server database to my nodejs application like this :

DAO.js

```
const sql = require('mssql')

class DAO {
    constructor() {
        this.sqlConfig = {user: 'connexionMartin', password: 'InfoMartin', server: '192.168.102.232\\SQLEXPRESS', database: 'PROFACE'}
    }

    async connect() {
        try {
            console.log("Connecting database.....");
            let pool = await sql.connect(this.sqlConfig);
            if (pool)
                console.log("Database connected");
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

    async getDataLastHour() {
        try {
            let result = await sql.query('SELECT * FROM PROFACE.dbo.SuiviProduction WHERE Time_Stamp >= DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()),0) AND DATEPART(HOUR,Time_Stamp) = DATEPART(HOUR,GETDATE())-1');
            console.dir(result);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
}
```

app.js

```
const Server = require('./server/Server');
const DAO = require('./server/DAO');
const express = require('express');

const server = new Server();
const dao = new DAO();

server.start();
dao.connect();
```

Now I want to request my database using `dao.getDataLastHour()` in app.js, but the function is executed before application is connected to database. I have tried to fix this problem by using promise, like this :

```
const promise = dao.connect();
promise.then(dao.getDataLastHour());
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Perhaps I don't use Promise correctly.

Comment: `connect()` method does not return a `Promise`

Comment: If you are using await, then you dont have to use then. In this case if sql.connect is returing a promise, you can either return that promise and use then to execute the callback or call connect with await and just return.

Comment: Can you check if the database connection is successful?

Comment: @Arun Selin I am using await but dao.getDataLastHour() is executed before database is connected ...

Comment: @Arun Selin yes connection is successful!

Comment: In this case, can you make sure if the sql.connect function return a promise or not. One other thing that can be done is sql.connect(config, function(err) { <<Within this function check if the connection is successful or not>>});

Answer (score 0):

To use a then in you function,it need to return any result and turn it in a promise, or not use await, might it will work!

```
    async connect() {

            console.log("Connecting database.....");
            sql.connect(this.sqlConfig).then(pool => {
              if (pool)
                console.log("Database connected");
            }).catch (err{ 
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
```

sorry for the bad identification!

Answer (score 0):

Your method : dao.connect() does not return a promise. 
So the first thing would be to change that method to return a promise which you can then listen to then decide whether to run a query or not. :

```
...
connect() {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            console.log("Connecting database.....");
            let pool = sql.connect(this.sqlConfig);
            if (pool)
                console.log("Database connected");
                resolve("Success");
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            reject(err);
        }
     });
}
...
```

And then call your connect method like this:

```
dao.connect().then(
    success => { ... }, // you can continue querying 
    error => { ... } // something went wrong
);
```

Also try to read a bit about how to use promises here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Differences between promise and async: [What is the difference between JavaScript promises and async await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34401389/what-is-the-difference-between-javascript-promises-and-async-await)

Comment: I try this but it doesn't work anyway SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: @MissKnacki I modified my answer. Removed await from the code.

Comment: I have an error : ConnectionError: Connection is closed., but no message that database is connected like I had before

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
connect() {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        let pool = sql.connect(this.sqlConfig, function(err) {
            if(!err) {
                resolve();
            }
            else {
                reject();
            }
        });
 });
}
 dao.connect().then(<<call function here>>)
```

Comment: I try this but it doesn't work anyway ```SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function```

Comment: @MissKnacki that was a typo. Can you call it without await.

Comment: Yes but I have an error : ```ConnectionError: Connection is closed.```, but no message that database is connected like I had before.

Comment: @MissKnacki sql.connect accepts a callback function. So you can move the promise resolve into that callback

Comment: @Node_Ninja what do you mean ?