# How to turn a function from async promise and callback to a .then promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to upsert data to my database by doing an update query and if `result.rowCount > 0` I `console.log ('UPDATE Rows affected: ', result.rowCount);` else inserting . This is the code I'm copying from which uses async and a callback:

```
(async () => {
   await client.query (updateQuery, (err, result)=>{
      try {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (result.rowCount > 0){
           console.log ('Rows affected: ', result.rowCount);
           return;
         } else {
           client.query(insertQuery, (error, res) =>{
           try {
             if (error) throw error;
             console.log ('Rows affected:', res.rowCount);
           }catch(er){
             console.log(er);
            }finally {
               //do something here
            }
          });
        }
       }catch (e){
         console.log(e);
        }
   });
  })().catch(e => console.log(e));
```

This code works if I'm trying to add it with the async and callback but how would I transform this to use .then?

Answer (score 1):

There are other responses in Stackoverflow that already explain what `async/await` are doing. [Like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34401662/2770608)

To your particular case in order to achieve what you are asking, assuming that your "client" returns a promise (judging by the fact that you can use await it looks like it does) remove the await and just call `then` for the successful path and `catch` for the error path and `finally` for the `finally` part, like this:

```
    client.query(updateQuery)
    .then((a) => {
      return a + 1;
    })
    .then((b) => {
       return b + 1; // b is whatever the previous `then` returned
    })
    .then((c) => {
      // something something
      return c;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // here be your error handling
    })
    .finally((x) => {
      // do a barrel roll
    })
```

Comment: But how would I get the result for the second query on this line `client.query(insertQuery, (error, res) =>{`. Do I need another `.then`?

Comment: @DDavis25 whatever is returned in the previously returned promised is the argument that is passed to the next `then`. If you return `client.query`, the next `then` will have whatever `client.query` returns, if you just return a value, like in my example (post edit) then that value is what will be passed as an argument to the next then.