# Async / Await does't hit code inside async {}

Tags: angular, asynchronous, async-await, angular7

I try to implement loading spinner with async/ await database loading but can't hit code inside my async methode.
My data loading looks like this

```
getServerList(){
    this.http.get('XXXX')
    .map((data : Response) =>{
      return data.json() as MyObject[];
    }).toPromise().then(x => {
      this.serverList = x;
    })
  }
```

And my function inside my component is

```
    async () => {

      try {
        await this.serverListService.getServerList()
      }catch{}
    }
```

Firs, i have a warning tell me that my await keyword is not usefull because there is nothing to await. So i decided to add an async keyword to my data loading like this

```
async getServerList(){
    this.http.get('http://localhost:6875/api/ServerList_Base')
    .map((data : Response) =>{
      return data.json() as ServerListBase[];
    }).toPromise().then(x => {
      return x;
    })
    return this.serverList
  }
```

So now my await is usefull but my problem is that the code never hit inside my async brackets. I mean the code inside

```
async () => {}
```

is never executed and i don't know why. I tried to lod it from the constructor / from the nginit from the ngAfterViewInit but nothing works

And Also when i try to remove these async brackets like this

```
 async loadDataFromDB(){

    await this.serverListService.getServerList()
    this.dataSource  = new MatTableDataSource()
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      this.showSpinner = false;
}
```

It doesn't wait the getServerList() before going to the second line "this.dataSource"...
I am used to using async/await in c#, maybe i miss something for angular.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Take the first version of `getServerList()`, add `return` to the first line (`return this.http.get('XXXX') ...`). You can't await something that doesn't return a promise.

Comment: why are you mixing promises and async/await, pick one and use it

Comment: `getServerList` needs to return the promise: `async getServerList(){ return 
this.http.get('http://localhost:6875/api/ServerList_Base')...`

Comment: `.toPromise().then(x => {  return x;  })` is doing literally nothing

Comment: @liam ok thanks, i think i need to have a deaper look on how promise works..

Comment: Or [observables](https://angular.io/guide/observables). Generally angular is built around observables not promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getServerList` should look like this

```js
getServerList(): Observabe<MyObject[]>{
    return this.http.get('XXXX')
    .pipe(
       map((data : Response) =>{
          return data.json() as MyObject[];
       })
    );
  }
```

You then consume it thus:

```js
getServerList().subscribe((data: MyObject[]) => {
   
});
```

I'd suggest you read the [docs on observables on the angular web page](https://angular.io/guide/observables) and the afore mentioned [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) question.

Promises, async/await and observables are all similar solutions to the same problem but they all work differently. Your code currently has a mix of all 3 of these. There are multiple ways to achieve the above but I would recommend you pick one of these solutions and stick to it instead of mixing them up. Mixing them up simply makes your code confusing.

- [What is the difference between Promises and Observables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364973/what-is-the-difference-between-promises-and-observables)
- [What is the difference between JavaScript promises and async await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34401389/what-is-the-difference-between-javascript-promises-and-async-await)