# i want to Call a function after previous function is complete reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to call a function when previous function is completed. I use `async` and `await`, but it does not work :

```
  const getDate = async () => {
await Object.keys(baskets || {}).forEach(vendorCode => {
  recalculateBill({
    calculateOrder: true,
    shop: Tools.pickVendorFiled(baskets[vendorCode]),
    shopex: tab === DELIVERY_TYPES.NORMAL
  })
})

getShopexInfo({ ids: basketIds })
}
```

Comment: use javascript promises

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between JavaScript promises and async await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34401389/what-is-the-difference-between-javascript-promises-and-async-await)

Answer (score 0):

Using async/await is quite tricky in **forEach** loop, maybe you can try switching to **for of** loop it works great with async/await and you will achieve what you want to
Or you also try doing it this way

```
 const getDate = async () => {
 Object.keys(baskets || {}).forEach(await(vendorCode) => {
  recalculateBill({
    calculateOrder: true,
    shop: Tools.pickVendorFiled(baskets[vendorCode]),
    shopex: tab === DELIVERY_TYPES.NORMAL
  })
})

getShopexInfo({ ids: basketIds })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for...in` loop instead of `Object.keys(baskets || {}).forEach`, in which await will work as expected:

```
async function getDate () {
  for (const vendorCode in baskets ) {
    await recalculateBill({ calculateOrder: true,
                            shop: Tools.pickVendorFiled(baskets[vendorCode]),
                            shopex: tab === DELIVERY_TYPES.NORMAL
                           });
  }
  getShopexInfo({ ids: basketIds })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have a loop, await a loop with inside some promises it's tricky, you need to use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) in order to wait all of them to be finished before continuing with the next function.

`Promise All` take an array of promises (I use `.map` and not `.forEach` to return an array of promises), and return a promise itself so you can just await  it.

```
const getDate = async () => {
    const basketsArr =  Object.keys(baskets || {});

  await Promise.all(basketsArr.map((vendorCode) => 
    await recalculateBill({
      calculateOrder: true,
      shop: Tools.pickVendorFiled(baskets[vendorCode]),
      shopex: tab === DELIVERY_TYPES.NORMAL
    })
  ))
  
  await getShopexInfo({ ids: basketIds })
}
```