# An "async" function versus a function that returns a "Promise"

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

An `async` function already returns a `Promise`:

```
const Area = async (L, B) => L * B;
console.log(await Area(5, 4));
Area(5, 4).then(r => console.log(r));
```

The above can also be written using a function that returns a `Promise`:

```
const pfArea = (L, B) => new Promise(resolve => resolve(L * B));
console.log(await pfArea(5, 4));
pfArea(5, 4).then(r => console.log(r));
```

What does the second method offer, besides the ability to return an error condition using the reject option?

Comment: `async function` returns a promise. The purpose of async/await is to simplify the syntax necessary to consume promise-based APIs.

Comment: Why are either of those functions async? Both of them resolve immediately and block the whole time

Comment: "*besides the ability to return an error condition using the reject option?*" in the first code block, a `throw` will also reject the promise

Comment: Also using `throw` is equivalent to rejecting the promise

Comment: `besides the ability to return an error condition` which you can do in an async function by returning a Promise.reject or by using `throw` ... so neither offer anything the other can't, except for simpler looking code when using async/await

Comment: Is this what you need? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34401389/what-is-the-difference-between-javascript-promises-and-async-await

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Am I correct to conclude that in the evolution of promises, the second method above came first, and async/await came later to do essentially the same thing with a nicer syntax?

Comment: "*Am I correct to conclude that in the evolution of promises, the second method above came first, and async/await came later*" yes. Promises were introduced in ES6. Well, even before that, as [the Promise/A+ spec](https://promisesaplus.com/) existed even earlier. Promises, as core part of JS, were added in ES6. Implementations existed as in like Bluebird or even jQuery. async/await is syntactic sugar over promises and was introduced in ES7. It was scheduled for ES6 release with promises but it failed to meet the deadline.